# Generate migration from MySQL schema

Tags: mysql, knex.js

converting a project and looking for a way to connect to DB schema, read it and generate knexJS migration files to integrate in new project.
Is there a way to do this? and how?

Comment: Please, ask a specific question. Your problem is too broad. Check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for more detailed guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to extract migration file for current schema of some database. If you really want to create one, it must be written manually.

But you don't even need one. You can just start using knex, with your old database dump and in the future when there should be changes done to the schema you can write new migrations for those specific incremental changes to the schema.

For running migrations you should use knex's migration functionality.